# Set up a temporary timer iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, methods, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a periodic call to a method in objective c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620109/how-to-make-a-periodic-call-to-a-method-in-objective-c)

I am making an app where when the user touches the screen, the following method is called:

```
- (void)explode:(int)x
```

The user only has to touch the screen once, but I want the method to be called repeatedly every 0.1 seconds for 100 times, and then it should stop being called.

Is there a way of setting up a 'temporary' timer like this on a method where an integer is being passed?

Comment: Yes, there are several ways, which would be revealed to you if you made the slightest effort to look for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a counter and the 'x' as into the timer's userInfo. Try this:

Create the timer in the method that's catching the touch event and pass a counter and the int 'x' into the userInfo:

```
NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
[userInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x] forKey:@"x"];
[userInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"counter"];

[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                        target:self
                      selector:@selector(timerMethod:)
                      userInfo:userInfo
                       repeats:YES];
```

Create the timer method, check the userInfo's number count, and invalidate the timer after 100 times:

```
- (void)timerMethod:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = timer.UserInfo;
    int x = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"x"] intValue];

    // your code here

    int counter = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"counter"] intValue];
    counter++;

    if (counter >= 100)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
    else
    {
        [userInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x] forKey:@"x"];
        [userInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:counter] forKey:@"counter"];
    }

}
```

Please also see the Apple docs on `NSTimer`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

Comment: what about passing the integer "x" to the method as i said in the question?

Comment: Yeah, you could pass it in via the timer's userInfo, if you'd like. Please see my edited answer above.

Comment: Yeah, so the userInfo is actually supposed to be a dictionary... see the revised answer above for better practice...