# How do I continually display the current time on an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a single view application in `Xcode` that simply updates the time every second in a label. I know how to get the current time (using `NSDate`) but where is the method that I would have it refresh in? All that I see in `ViewController` is the following methods:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
```

And all that I see in AppDelegate is the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions                            
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

To my knowledge, none of these methods look like they are capable of updating the time constantly. I want it to display the time sort of like a clock (it continually updates). How would I do this? I was expecting there to be some kind of loop method to do this in but it doesn't look like there is one.

Comment: Try NSTimer:

 https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a periodic call to a method in objective c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620109/how-to-make-a-periodic-call-to-a-method-in-objective-c)

Comment: your label must be present in a viewcontroller. So it is none of concern with app delegate. Use `NSTimer` for periodically updating label time

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :)

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    NSDateFormatter *timeformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeformatter setTimeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [timeformatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];

   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(UpdateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

 }

-(void)UpdateTime:(id)sender
{
   NSString *Time  = [timeformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
   NSLog(@"Time == %@",Time);
}
```